# how do i add more details for a checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a checkbox which lists all the extras I have. I've currently got it working so it shows as a list and the user can select which extra they'd like.

I've used the following for this:

```
<div class="field">
<%= form.label "Add Extras:" %>
<div class="row" >
<% @extras.each do |extra|  %>
<div class="col-lg-4" align="center">
  <%= extra.item %>
  <div id="img-box">
    <% if not extra.image.blank? %>
      <%= image_tag extra.image, :size => "200x200" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag "no-image.jpg", :size => "200x200" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  £<%= extra.price %>
  </br>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
   <%= form.collection_check_boxes :extra_ids, Extra.all, :id, :item  do |b| %>
  <div class="collection-check-box">
    <%= b.check_box %>
    <%= b.label %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

[image]

How would I get the check boxes to display next to item name above the image?

schema.rb

```
create_table "extras_reservations", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "reservation_id", null: false
  t.integer "extra_id", null: false
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What I understand is that the show button is covering the checkbox, is that your problem or do I get it all wrong?

Comment: Sorry no, I've just shown an example the screenshot above is from my extra show.html.erb I've got a reservation page where I'd like to list all the extra's like I have above. Currently  I have a checkbox and the name of the item.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please see edit. I just want to know how I'd get the checkbox to display next to item type i.e. sat-nav rather then below it in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `collection_check_boxes` section, and put the `checkbox` inside the loop like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "reservation[extra_ids][]", nil %>
<% @extras.each do |extra|  %>
  <div class="col-lg-4" align="center">
    <%= check_box_tag 'reservation[extra_ids][]', extra.id, @reservation.extra_ids.include?(extra.id), id: dom_id(extra) %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(extra), extra.item %>

    # ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And don't forget to permit `:extra_ids`

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot to mention the check boxes are being used to add extras to the reservation. The checkboxes when selected save to a reservation_extra table. How would i get your solution to do the same? Your solutions does put the check boxes where I'd like but doesn't save to the database.

Comment: Could you show me your `reservation_extra` schema and model?

Comment: I've used the following website to help set it up: https://www.sitepoint.com/save-multiple-checkbox-values-database-rails/  There's no model as such in the reservation.rb I've put `has_and_belongs_to_many :extra`  and in the extra.rb I've put `has_and_belongs_to_many :reservation` I've added the scheme on the initial question.

Comment: Hi @MAhmed, I've just updated the answer. Please have a look!